# Java - query.getSingleResult() Poor performance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a query which counts rows from a database, when I execute it using query.getSingleResult() has a really poor performance (about 13 secs) but if I execute the same query using query.getResultList() has a high performance (about 1 or 2 seconds) . I don't understand why this happens.

I am using Query from javax.persistence.Query the framework is Hibernate

The code is something like this:

```
StringBuilder countJpql = new StringBuilder("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Entity e");
Query countQuery = em.createQuery(countJpql.toString())
Long count = (Long) countQuery.getSingleResult()
```

and

```
StringBuilder countJpql = new StringBuilder("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Entity e");
Query countQuery = em.createQuery(countJpql.toString())
List<Long> countList = countQuery.getResultList()
```

where em is EntityManager

Comment: Can you show the code? Sql

Comment: I am using Query from javax.persistence.Query the framework is Hibernate

Comment: If you don't understand something you look in the log of the JPA provider ... aka "debugging"

Comment: Posting the SQLs you are using for getSingleResult and getResultList would help.

Comment: It's probably you are using a wrong sql

Comment: it's the same query in both cases

Comment: Can it be that you try `getResultList()` after `getSingleResult()` and the DB caches the result somehow? Looking at the source code, `getSingleResult` actually calls `getResultList` and then does not do anything special.

Comment: Are you timing just these 3 lines of code or your timer has other lines that may be contributing to the delay?

Comment: @lexicore I don't have a getResultList() after getSingleResult(), I replaced the line to compare the performance, thanks for review the source code

Comment: @sahi There isn't other lines, I replace the code to compare the performance and I take the time manually

Comment: You can activate the hibernate's log, and compare the generated queries